# SQL delete leaving the ID not deleted

Tags: java, android

When I use deleteRow method it deletes all the values of a row(imagine row 2 of a total 0f 5 rows) but when I use my getLastID method it still returns  the lastID 5 as if there still are 5 numbers. Here are my methods

Method to delete all the values in the row whit the id given

```
   public Integer deleteRow(String id){


    return   database.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID=?",new String[]{id});



}
```

Method to getLastID

```
    public int getLastId() {
    String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    int id = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;

}
```

Comment: What does your delete method do exactly?

Comment: @rabbit guy Deletes the values from the row whit the ID given

Comment: It is deleting all the values but not the ID, it leaves a gap , a row whit , imagine ID 2 but no values, just null spaces!

Comment: The id is a PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete just eliminates one row with the ID given, but that does not mean that the last row is deleted, imagine you have this table :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       other      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

if you do `max(id)` it will return `3`, if you delete the ID `2`, you end up with the table like this :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       other      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And your `max(id)` will keep returning  `3` because that function just returns the higher value on the column.

Answer (score 0):

The database is doing exactly what it is designed to do. It keeps the last used ID and increments it by one each time a new ID is assigned.

It does not keep a pool of the all the ID's assigned and attempt to reuse ones where the rows are deleted. That what be very complicated and slow.